# Bizarre behavior with simple htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, session, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I use this simple rewrite rule in my htaccess to redirect any file path that does not exists to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

That works perfectly fine, but I have little problem, in index.php file there is one line that unsets previous session:

```
index.php
.....
session_unset()
.....
```

Now I have another file register.php which uses it's own session data, when I run register.php it works fine but the session is unset, it seems index.php is executed first then register.php!! I doubled check that by commenting out the session_unset() function in index.php and the session is working fine in register.php

What is going on? how this happened if no redirection occurred to index.php in fist place?

Comment: You are **internally** rewriting to `index.php` so the file is being called. It doesn't need to be a "real" redirection.  How else would the $_GET variable work inside index.php and show the file path requested if it wasn't being called/requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! this is one of the most tiny and unexpected bugs I have ever seen (lol)
I discovered the cause of the problem when I noticed that this only occurs with register.php, the reason of why index.php is called before register.php is simply because of a wrong css path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
```

Which in my case should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

What happened is that because the path of stylesheet.css does not exist the server will rewrite it to index.php and then index.php is run deleting all the session, but because this is just css include you will not see this and you will stay on register.php! When the path was fixed the problem was solved, I learn something new everyday.